# Displaying normal size symbols in formula

Tags: equations

How can I make the following part of code:

```
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n w_{ij}
```

in normal size and not in subscript size?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
I = \frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n w_{ij}}
\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n w_{ij}(x_i - \bar{x})(x_j -
  \bar{x})}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add a `\displaystyle` directive in the denominator of the first `\frac` expression:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
I = \frac{n}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n w_{ij}}
    \frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n w_{ij}(x_i 
      - \bar{x})(x_j - \bar{x})}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Addendum: Technically, without the `displaystyle` directive, the main elements of expressions in the numerator and denominator of a `\frac` command that's part of a displayed equation are not in "(sub)script" style but in "text style".

Answer (score 2):

as i interpret this question, you want the sums in the denominator of the first fraction to be the same size as those in the second fraction, but you want them to be shown with sub/superscripts, not with limits.  add `\displaystyle` to that expression, and insert `\nolimits` after each `\sum`, as

```
{\displaystyle\sum\nolimits_{i=1}^n \sum\nolimits_{j=1}^n w_{ij}}
```

giving this result:

[image: display with adjusted fraction]

Comment: Thank you. Now my formula looks nice. Now I'd like to add an explanation to it, and when I type $\bar{x}$ out of the equation environment, the symbol is not displayed. How can I do that?

Comment: @Costi -- i can't think of any reason that `$\bar{x}$` wouldn't be shown in accompanying ordinary text, like a following paragraph. please be more specific about the form you want your explanation to take.

Comment: This is what I get when trying to run \bar{x} in normal text: ! Package amsmath Error: \bar allowed only in math mode.

Comment: @Costi -- yes, you need to enclose it in `$...$`.  you said in your first comment that dollar signs were used.  if it *is* in dollar signs and still gets that error message, then it will be necessary to see a working example, complete with document class and relevant packages.  put this in a new question, as extended code is nearly indecipherable in a comment.

Comment: \documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\begin{document}

$\bar{x}$￼ 

\end{document}

Comment: There's definitely a conflict between $\bar{x}$ and either mathdesign or fontenc.

Comment: i've tested every package except the `bitstream-charter` component of `mathdesign`.  we don't have that font.  i'm unable to reproduce the error you report.  `$\bar{x}$` invariably appears as expected with no problem.